# Combo Box selecting First Record and not the defined record

Tags: vba, ms-access

first time asking here because i'm stumped!

I have a MS Access Form with 2 combo boxes:
First combo box (cboPub) selects a Publisher which then filters the second combo box (cboTitle), this works fine however the pulled record is the first record and not the one that meets the criteria.

Code below:

```
Private Sub cboPub_AfterUpdate()
cboTitle = Null
cboTitle.Requery
End Sub

Sub cboTitle_AfterUpdate()
    ' Find the record that matches the control.
    Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[Supplier] = """ & Me![cboTitle] & """"

    Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark

End Sub
```

I suspect it is because of the line here:

```
Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[Supplier] = """ & Me![cboTitle] & """"
```

but i dont know what to change to have it select the correct record.

Comment: What is the RowSource of cboTitle? Have you step debugged - what value does cboTitle show in code? Try dot instead of bang (!) when referencing controls.

Comment: Have a look at [.FindFirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao) and see how to handle nothing found, Check combos returnval with `Debug.Print Me.[cboTitle].Value` I assume box not bound to displayed value (show recordsource)!

Comment: Row Source of cboTitle is:  SELECT DISTINCTROW [Raw Material Master].PubID, [Raw Material Master].[Raw Material], [Raw Material Master].[CAS Number], [Raw Material Master].[PRISM CODE]
FROM [Raw Material Master] INNER JOIN [Raw Material Details] ON [Raw Material Master].PubID = [Raw Material Details].[Raw Material]
ORDER BY [Raw Material Master].[Raw Material];

Answer (score 0):

A common task is to filter the data in a form's details section from unbound combo boxes in the form header section. (don't set the comboboxs' data sources)  I assume that is what you are trying to do because me in the afterupdate event refers to the form.  If so set the forms filter rather than messing with the forms record source. Your second problem is cboTitle's afterupdate event doesn't fire when cbotitle's value is changed through vba code.  So put all the code in cboPub.

```
Private Sub cboPub_AfterUpdate()
'cboTitle = dlookup("Title", "SomeTable", "SupplierID = " & cboPub.value) 'how I filtered cboTitle
Me.Filter = "SupplierID = " & cboPub.Value 
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub

Private Sub cboTitle_AfterUpdate()
Debug.Print "check the immediate window for how cboTitle's after update event does not fire when cboTitle is updated with VBA"
End Sub
```

warning: treat this as pseudo code; the exact filter depends on how Supplier, Publisher, and Title are related in your tables and combo boxes.

Explanation:  I think the programmers behind access intentionally forced us to set up our forms entirely at design time.  No matter what I have tried Access does not display runtime changes to it's record source in any acceptable fashion.  It is the access way or the high way.  Linking up your record source and form variables at design time then filtering is the only approach I have found that works.  I assume the reasons behind why you cannot trigger an afterupdate event through code are similar.

Comment: Seems like you doing sth. wrong. Where is your problem, changing record-source at run-time (maybe query fields have different names, so Control Source needs updating) Reason why `AfterUpdate` is not trigered by code, it's designed to catch changes by gui. If you want to catch changes by code, use code!